# Entity Framework Code First - Mapping and Metadata not found exception

Tags: entity-framework

Subclassing entities and adding sub-class instance to the Context's DbSet collection causes the following error `Mapping and metadata information could not be found for EntityType 'Namespace_Name.SubClass_Entity_Name'`.

**Details:**

The context class has a property DbSet.
We have couple of entities in different assemblies,

1. BaseClass (BaseClass belonging to Assembly1)
2. DerivedClass : BaseClass (DerivedClass belonging to Assembly2)

At run-time when we add an instance of derived class to the Context, we get the above mentioned exception.

Note: When the DerivedClass was belonging to the same assembly as BaseClass this exception doesn't occur.

**Question:**
Why do we have this issue, just because the sub-class is belonging to a separate assembly?
Why don't we face this issue for sub-classes belonging to the same assembly?

---

**UPDATE:**

I found a fix, which is to override OnModelCreating method and register the DerivedClass as follows, `modelBuilder.Entity< DerivedClass>();`.

Comment: Since you have an answer, you might want to enter it below, as an answer to your own question. You can then mark it as the "accepted answer", making it more clear to anyone else running into the same problem and reading this post.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. The solution that I found seem to be a work around. My actual question remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Another Workaround:
If you use TPT mapping you have to register your derived class too, but it kind of makes more sense that way.

```
Map(m => 
{
  m.ToTable("BaseClassTableName")
}.Map<DerivedClass>(m =>
{
  m.ToTable("DerivedClassTableName")
}
```